# On blackberry : making a phonecall within an app on user action without J2ME?

Tags: blackberry, phone-call

Is there a way of making a phonecall within an application using Browser application development ? (for example using a link with a protocol similar to 'mailto:user@example.com' but that would make phonecalls instead of sending mails.)

If not, is it possible to make phonecalls using the Rapid application development ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this an app hosted in a browser, Blackberry respects WAP conventions for encoding a phone number.

Here's an example snipppit for displaying a number that is callable via a Blackberry device:

> <a href='wtai://wp/mc;5551231367' title='Call'>555.123.1367</a>

I've been using this approch for some time now and it works for me. When the user clicks the link, a dialog from the OS pops up and asks if you would like to call this number.

**Additional Information**
I also recommend checking out Blackberry's additional resources on development. Since the current browser is still in the stone age compared to iPhone/Android it's worth seeing what's possible.
http://na.blackberry.com/eng/support/docs/subcategories/?userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Browser